# No such file or directory in Google Cloud Bucket Problem

Tags: python, sockets, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to implement my socket server and my model in Google Cloud, however when I try to run the python script. It gives me an error of "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'trained_model.p'".

The trained model is in the bucket and I changed the code of the python script to match it with the Google Cloud.

**Here's the portion of the python script:**

```
def Main():
    model = pickle.load(open('gs://liwanag_model/trained_model.p','rb'))
    ...
```

How can I successfully access the trained_model file inside the bucket?

Comment: If it says the file is not there, that's almost certainly the explanation. We can't troubleshoot this without access to the resource.

Comment: But is the specification of the directory is correct? Like is it gs://... in Google Cloud? @tripleee

Comment: What's your dependencies? Reading in GCS is not python native